# How to easily clear the recent Google search history in Safari 4 for Mac?

Tags: mac, browser, safari, privacy

**Safari 4** introduced a beefed-up Google search field on its toolbar that provides suggestions as you type, which is wonderful. What's not so wonderful is that it remembers ***everything*** you search *without an option to disable it* or clear it easily.

I can't figure out why Apple removed the "Clear Search" option from the drop down menu which displays past searches. I've managed to get the option back by hacking Safari's plist file but it's too much work.

Is there an ***easier*** way to do this, without going nuclear by using **File->Reset Safari...** or using the plist hack?

Comment: Curious - with the latest Safari version (4.0.4) I do see a "Clear Recent Searches" option in the drop down menu.

Comment: That's the answer, Jonik. I have it there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jonik suggested in a comment: there's a "Clear Recent Searches" option in the drop down menu.

[image: Clear recent searches option in dropdown]

(At least since Safari 4.0.4 or earlier)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Safari user, but here's what I found:

The easiest way is to clear all your browsing history (click on the Clear History button in Full History search or choose History > Clear History). This will apparently also clear the search history.

Second method is:

1. Go to Settings/Safari
2. Change your search engine (switch from Google to Yahoo! or vise versa)
3. Launch Safari
4. Go to Settings/Safari
5. Clear History, Cookies, and Cache
6. Change your search engine back to what you had originally

Comment: No, that's not it. You'll understand what I'm talking about if you use Safari. What you suggested is the nuclear method I was talking about. Thanks anyway Harry. ;-)

Comment: Well, that's apparently the only solution in existence, according to several forum threads.